# What is the probability that a graph containing n nodes with k random edges each will be strongly connected?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, graph-theory

Consider a "random" undirected graph, with n nodes and (on average) k edges assigned to each node, such that the edge connects the node to a randomly chosen node in the graph. What is the probability that this graph will be connected, i.e. contain a path from every node to every other node?

Comment: Do you mean, in your construction of a random graph, that an edge between two nodes occurs with probability $k/n$, and that the probability of an edge is independent of the probability of all other edges?

Comment: "strongly connected" is a term used for directed graphs, but there is no hint of directed edges in the remainder of the question.

Comment: the graph should be undirected, fixed. i just mean to ask what the probability is that every node has some path to every other node.

Comment: @TomHallward that seems like it would work for the construction, because that should result in nk total edges

Comment: To @vadim123's point, here is a clarification of the notions of strongly directed and directed. [Link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6833/difference-between-connected-vs-strongly-connected-vs-complete-graphs)

Comment: Assuming the question is about graphs, see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model#Properties_of_G(n,_p)).  If $np>(1+\epsilon)\log n$, then the graph will almost surely be connected.  If instead $np<(1-\epsilon) \log n$, then the graph will almost surely be disconnected.

Comment: @vadim123 looks really useful! may i ask what the epsilon represents?

Comment: any (small) positive constant

Comment: @vadim123 how do I choose epsilon and why does it matter?

Comment: @vadim123, can you make a quick answer to my question about the erdos-renyi? it was exactly what i was looking for and i want to mark you as best answer if you care. it helped me a huge amount with my paper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model#Properties_of_G(n,_p)) about the Erdos-Renyi model. Two key properties are:

1. If $pn<(1-\epsilon)\log n$, then the graph is almost surely disconnected.
2. If $pn>(1+\epsilon)\log n$, then the graph is almost surely connected.

Answer (score 2):

Let me first introduce some terminology: $G(n,p)$ is a random graph on $n$ vertices in which each edge is put with probability $p$.

A classical result in the theory of random graphs states that if $p = \frac{\log n + c}{n}$ (where $c$ is constant) then the probability that a graph drawn according to $G(n,p)$ is connected tends to $e^{-e^{-c}}$ as $n \to \infty$.

Using this, you can show that if $c(n) \to -\infty$ and $p = \frac{\log n + c(n)}{n}$ then the probability that a graph drawn according to $G(n,p)$ is connected tends to $0$, and if $c(n) \to \infty$ the probability tends to $1$.

You can obtain similar results in the $G(n,m)$ model, in which you put $m$ random edges. In this case instead of $p = \frac{\log n + c}{n}$ you should consider $m = \frac{n}{2} (\log n + c)$.

Finally, if you draw a random $d$-regular graph on $n$ vertices for $d \geq 3$, then the probability that it is connected tends to $1$ as $n \to \infty$. (For $d = 2$, it tends to $0$.)